# Spring-mybatis connection fails with UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mybatis

I am relatively new to Spring, and am having problem with establishing spring-mybatis setup environment. Here is my code. The exception I am getting is

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController for com.infosender.service.UserServiceImpl.

I don't get this issue. Because the UserServiceImpl object is autowired in LoginController and UserServiceImpl class is autowired to UserDaoMapper interface, there should be a bean named UserServiceImpl. Why could be the reason for the bean not found?

```
package com.infosender.controller;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.infosender.user.User;
import com.infosender.user.UserDao;
import com.infosender.user.UserDaoMapper;
import com.infosender.service.UserService;
import com.infosender.service.UserServiceImpl;;


@Controller
public class LoginController {

    //UserService userService = UserService.getInstance();
    @Autowired
    UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleRequestInternal(
            @ModelAttribute("username") String user_id,
            @ModelAttribute("password") String user_pw
            ) {
        User user = null;
        try {
            user = userServiceImpl.getUserByIdAndPw(user_id, user_pw);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(user == null) {
            return "login_fail";
        }
        return "main_menu";     
    }
}
```

And here is UserService and UserServiceImpl

```
package com.infosender.service;

import java.sql.SQLException;    
import javax.inject.Inject;    
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;    
import com.infosender.user.User;
import com.infosender.user.UserDao;    
public interface UserService {

    public User getUserByIdAndPw(String user_id, String user_pw)throws SQLException;
}

package com.infosender.service;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.infosender.user.User;
import com.infosender.user.UserDao;
import com.infosender.user.UserDaoMapper;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDaoMapper userDaoMapper;    

    public User getUserByIdAndPw(String user_id, String user_pw)throws SQLException {
        return userDaoMapper.getUserByIdAndPw(user_id, user_pw);
    }   
}
```

Here I have UserDao and UserDaoMapper

```
package com.infosender.user;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class UserDao implements UserDaoMapper{

    @Autowired  
    private SqlSessionTemplate sqlSession;


    public void setSqlSessionTemplate(SqlSessionTemplate sqlSession) {
        this.sqlSession = sqlSession;
    }

    public User getUserByIdAndPw(String user_id, String user_password) {
        UserDaoMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(UserDaoMapper.class);
        return mapper.getUserByIdAndPw(user_id, user_password);

        //return sqlSession.selectOne("com.infosender.user.UserDaoMapper.getUserByIdAndPw");        
    }   
}

package com.infosender.user;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

public interface UserDaoMapper {
    public User getUserByIdAndPw(@Param("user_id")String user_id,@Param("user_password")String user_password);  
}
```

And the below is root-context.xml configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:mybatis-spring="http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.3.xsd
        http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring-1.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>



    <!-- org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource -->
    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/InfoSender"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/WEB_INF/spring/mybatis/mybatis-config.xml"></property>
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:*/mappers/*mapper.xml"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

<!--    <bean id="userDaoMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.infosender.user.UserDaoMapper"></property>
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"></property>

    </bean>
     -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.infosender.*" />

    </beans>
```

Here is the entire error log

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.infosender.service.UserService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:696)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:662)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:587)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:526)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5337)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.infosender.service.UserService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1646)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1205)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: At a galance, you should use interface instead of the concrete implementation, in this case, change to `@Autowired UserService userService;` in your code.

Comment: Thanks @LipingHuang , but even with that fixed, it is still failing with no such bean named 'user service'..

Comment: then you need register your custom user detail service and annotate with spring `@Bean` annotation.

Comment: @LipingHuang But instead of registering the UserServiceImpl bean with bean, I used Service annotation to create such bean. Shouldn't it work..?

Comment: Can you post the entire stacktrace?

Comment: @h3adache I posted the error stacktrace above. I changed some settings according to Liping Huang's suggestion

Comment: What happens if you remove .* from component-scan? ex. `<context:component-scan base-package="com.infosender" />`

Answer (score 1):

To anybody who might view this page.

The problem was in fact in my web.xml file. There I declared two xml files with contextConfigLocation tag: root-context.xml and mybatis-config.xml.
What I did was that I wrote them 'separately', so that (I presume) the latter has somehow overwritten the former one, not creating the sqlSession beans as it ought to.

There were some mistakes in the code as the comments have suggested. But this was the main reason for not created beans.